# How to connect Arduino with ESP8266-11 WiFi module to 000webhost (free webhosting)

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, http

I want to know how to connect my Arduino to my website on 000webhost.com (free webhosting account). I'm using ESP-11 WiFi module and it is connected to the internet.

This is my Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial ESP11 = SoftwareSerial(10,11); // RX, TX
#define DEBUG true

// WIFI SHIELD DECLARATION
String ssid = "\"SampleSSID\"";
String pass = "\"SamplePass\"";
String tcp = "\"TCP\"";
String remoteip = "\"jvystocksystem.000webhostapp.com\"";
String portnum = "80";

void setup(){          
  ESP11.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // configure as access point and Client
  sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendData("AT+GMR\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // View version Info
  sendData("AT+CWLAP\r\n",5000,DEBUG); // List all available AP's*/
  sendData("AT+CWJAP=" + ssid + "," + pass + "\r\n",10000,DEBUG); // Connect to AP
  sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n",2000,DEBUG); //Single TCP Connections 
  sendData("AT+CIPSTART="+ tcp +"," + remoteip + "," + portnum + "\r\n",3000,DEBUG); // Start connecting to localhost <link id>,<type>,<remote IP>,<Port Number>

  String getStr = "GET /getCpno.php?user_type=admin HTTP/1.0"; // Getting info from my online database through my online website
  getStr += "\r\n\r\n";
  String cmd;
  // send data length
  cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  cmd += String(getStr.length());
  sendData(cmd + "\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
  sendData(getStr,3000,DEBUG);
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
// For ESP8266
  if(ESP11.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {


    if(ESP11.find("+IPD,"))
    {
     delay(1000); // wait for the serial buffer to fill up (read all the serial data)
     // get the connection id so that we can then disconnect
     int connectionId = ESP11.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48

     ESP11.find("pin="); // advance cursor to "pin="

     int pinNumber = (ESP11.read()-48)*10; // get first number i.e. if the pin 13 then the 1st number is 1, then multiply to get 10
     pinNumber += (ESP11.read()-48); // get second number, i.e. if the pin number is 13 then the 2nd number is 3, then add to the first number

     digitalWrite(pinNumber, !digitalRead(pinNumber)); // toggle pin    

     // make close command
     String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
     closeCommand+="\r\n";

     sendData(closeCommand,1000,DEBUG); // close connection
    }
  }
}

/*
* Name: sendData
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/

String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{

    String response = ""; // ESP8266 sendData String
    ESP11.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(ESP11.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = ESP11.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);

    }
    return response;
}
```

But my code is not returning the value I want from the database, instead I'm getting this in my serial monitor:

[image: Serial monitor]

I hope you guys can help me with my code.

Comment: Why are you using software serial on an Arduino Mega? It has 4 hardware serial ports.

Comment: i dont know how to use the other ports, eh

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial

Comment: its work for me thanks you master you save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server is using virtual hosts. Unless you tell it to which virtual host are you making a request, the server won't know where to send the request and generate an error.

You need to add the required header `Host`, which tell it just that.

Make the proper request like this:

```cpp
String getStr = "GET /getCpno.php?user_type=admin HTTP/1.1\r\n";
getStr += "Host: jvystocksystem.000webhostapp.com\r\n"; // add the required header
getStr += "\r\n";
```

Comment: You are setting up a single socket mode by `AT+CIPMUX=0`, therefore all commands(TX/RX) should not be contain **connection id**. So you could close the connection using `sendData("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n",1000,DEBUG);`, and the code which related **connection id** also could be remove. The number which following the `+IPD,` is the total response bytes, which counted by following `:`.